# Присубстантивное определение (?)

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, определения, дополнение

Командование армией — здесь *армией* является дополнением или определением?

Comment: Зная русский максимум на уровне полного среднего образования (т. е. не являясь языковедом), не могу понять вопрос. Слово «армия» признаком не является (вместо этого [называет предмет](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/905727)), [прилагательным/причастием/местоимением/числительным](https://www.calc.ru/Opredeleniye-Kak-Vtorostepenniy-Chlen-Predlozheniya.html) не выражено, так что определением однозначно быть не может.

Comment: @Arhad но ведь командование _какое?_ армией...

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, это синкретичный член предложения - и то и другое возможно.

Однако **преобладает** синтаксическое значение  **дополнения**, выражающего объект действия, такое дополнение употребляется при глаголах, а также при образованных от них сущ-х : Отчёт (о чём?) о работе - отчитываться (о чём?) о работе. Работа (над чем?) над докладом - работать (над чем?) над докладом. **Командование (кем? чем?) армией - командовать (кем? чем?) армией.**

Здесь есть и оттенок определения - характеристика предмета по степени распространения влияния, если здесь слово командование в значении "Лица, осуществляющие управление войсками", а не "процесс управления".
Командование (какое?) армией (= армейское, в отличие от полкового например).

Но  доминирует  всё-таки функция объекта и синтаксическое значение дополнения, а значение несогласованного определения вторично.

Answer (score 1):

Командование какое? Армией. Такой вопрос совсем не подходит и не звучит.

Командование чем? Армией. Всё звучит и подходит. То есть это дополнение.